# Is there any other alternative for IWorkflowInstanceExtension?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I am using bookmark in my code and resuming it from other class which is derived from `IWorkflowInstanceExtension` . I s there any alternative which i can use of IWorkflowInstanceExtension. what is advantage of using IWorkflowInstanceExtension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IWorkflowInstanceExtension` is typically used for activities that require extensions to be provided, without the workflow host needing to define the extensions. Also, an implementation of `IWorkflowInstanceExtension` is needed for host types that do not provide the ability to define extensions such as `WorkflowInvoker` or `WorkflowServiceHost`.

In your case, you are seeking an alternative for resuming bookmarks without needing to go through implementing the `IWorkflowInstanceExtension` interface. To do this, you can use the `WorkflowApplication` type to host your workflow, which has the `ResumeBookmark` method that you can invoke when you want to.